# Can the door in the Epilogue be opened?

Tags: the-turing-test

At the Epilogue of The Turing Test, there is a locked door with a large section of energy orb containers next to it. There are a few energy orbs of differing variety (blue, purple, green, and red) scattered around, but eventually the game takes away your Energy Manipulation Tool.

[image: The Door in Question.]

I see that there is a disconnect on this contraption; however, is it possible to solve a puzzle for this locked door? I haven't found any sources to indicate that it is.

Comment: Could you post an image of the door you're talking about?

Comment: @Vemonus Done!!

Comment: ah okay, that's the door I thought you were talking about. Let me see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, this door is not able to be opened.

In this [walkthrough for Chapter 7 and the epilogue](http://guides.gamepressure.com/theturingtest/guide.asp?ID=37230), there are no listed puzzles to do in the epilogue (and the image embedded even has this door in it).

Furthermore, from the same site, the [secrets guide](http://guides.gamepressure.com/theturingtest/guide.asp?ID=37191) does not make any mention of a secret door in the Epilogue. From what I can tell, the secret doors are all related to a Steam achievement, but this particular door is not related to any, which leads me to believe that it's not a secret door.

Also, you mentioned this in the question, but the cable intended to power the door appears to be broken in multiple places.

All signs point to this door being unopenable.

Comment: That's a shame, it could have been something neat to try and solve. I'm not sure there's enough orbs available anyway before your device gets taken away. Still, having solved the boolean puzzle, I thought perhaps there was something even more challenging in this door. Thanks for looking though!